# Getting distance between DEM's zero elevation and earth's center

Tags: python, gdal, dem, elevation

I'm using the DHM25 DEM available here:

https://www.swisstopo.admin.ch/en/geodata/height/dhm25.html

EPSG:21781+5728

(Swiss CH1903 / LV03 + LN02 height)

I need to use the earth's radius under Switzerland for some trig calculations. My 3 options are:

1. Just use the average earth's radius (mean global radius according to Wikipedia =  6371008.7714 meters).
2. Calculate the radius under the specific DEM (height from earth center to 0m in DEM) at each point in the DEM separately... I assume this is the most accurate, but might not be necessary.
3. Assuming the min and max radii aren't very far apart in option 2, calculate a single "local" radius, using the DEM's average.

Option 3 is my preference by far (it greatly simplifies the calculations I need to do), but I would need to look at the difference between min and max radii to make an informed decision.

I don't know how to do options 2 and 3.

**How can I determine the height of a DEM above the earth center, either at each DEM point or averaged over the DEM?**

I'm using Python and GDAL for everything ("from osgeo import gdal, osr, ogr", etc), so code/pseudocode is sought.

Comment: GIS SE isn't really a code provisioning service. In fact, it's the opposite -- You need to provide your (nonfunctional) code, and we'll try to help you fix it. Since we're a *problem-solving* site, we expect a level of due diligence, which includes a making a best attempt to complete the task. This assures the the problem is sufficiently focused (and sometimes, by documenting the problem, you'll find the answer on your own).

Comment: Make yourself comfortable with the difference between ellipsoidal and geoid height (plenty of information if you google for it). Make sure what you need, what is your intention, what you need this for. Then also have a look at the CRS definition which includes values for the lengths of ellipsoid axes (like e.g. `ELLIPSOID["Bessel 1841",6377397.155,299.1528128`)

Comment: To get you started, try converting a pair of geographic coordinates to Cartesian with pyproj. Once in a Euclidean space, the distance to the origin according to Pythagoras. But a warning too, that is far from being a radius of the ellipsoid: a line from the center of the Earth to a point on the ellipsoid (with some exceptions) is not perpendicular to the surface of the ellipsoid. Much less to the surface of the geoid from which the heights of your dem are measured orthogonally.